# How to freeze a row/column in tkinter canvas scrolling?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In python `tkinter` `Canvas`, I am looking for a way to freeze the first column when scrolling horizontally and freeze the first row in vertical scrolling. Something similar to Excel where the title column and row can be freezed in a table.

Below is an example code for a customer database. This code opens a window with grid of `Entry` boxes/ labels in a canvas where the customer data can be entered for 100 customers. A table like format is created by placing entry boxes and labels into a frame and then placing the frame into the canvas using `create_window()` in python

See the image far below showing the output `tkinter` window with the canvas. If the output grid is assumed as an excel like table, row 0 has labels (customer 1, 2 .... ) and column 0 has the description of the data to be input. While scrolling in x and y these labels vanish. What I am trying to do is:

1. A way to freeze column 0 (data description) when scrolling in x direction
2. Freeze row 0 (customer number) when scrolling in y direction

---

My current code:

```
from tkinter import *

class database(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, root, **kwargs)
        self.frame = Frame(root, background = "blue")

        self.scrolly = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient = "vertical")
        self.scrollx = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient = "horizontal")

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, bg = "pink", width = 500, height = 175)
        self.canvas_frame = Frame(self.canvas)

        #List of customer details
        self.customer_database = ["Name", "DOB", "Address", "Phone No", "Hobbies", "Profession"]

        #Define the number of customer records to collect
        self.no_of_customers = 100

        #Creating an 2D array of entry widgets to collect customer records
        self.entry = [[Entry(self.canvas_frame) for i in range (self.no_of_customers)] for j in range (len(self.customer_database))]

        #Creating labels to display in a tabular form within a frame which will be inserted into a canvas using create_window
        for i in range(len(self.customer_database)):
            Label(self.canvas_frame, text = self.customer_database[i]).grid(row = i+1, column = 0)

        for i in range(self.no_of_customers):
            Label(self.canvas_frame, text = "customer " + str(i+1)).grid(row = 0, column = i+1)

        #Inserting the 2D entry widget array in the canvas frame
        for i in range(self.no_of_customers):
            for j in range(len(self.customer_database)):
                self.entry[j][i].grid(row = j+1, column = i+1)

        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.scrolly.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "ns")
        self.scrollx.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "ew")
        self.scrolly.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollx.config(command = self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scrolly.set, xscrollcommand = self.scrollx.set)

        self.canvas.create_window(0,0, window = self.canvas_frame, anchor = "nw")
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.frame.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        print("inside")
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))


root = Tk()
frame = database(root)
root.geometry("400x400")
root.mainloop()
```

Output image:

[image: screenshot of output image]

Comment: How are you defining a column? The canvas itself doesn't have the concept of rows and columns, and scrolling on a canvas is all or nothing. Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates how you are creating columns.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, I have expanded on my question with a example code and a link to an image showing how the output looks. I am using create_window() to place a frame (with lables and entry boxes in grid) into a canvas. So it's its not exactly a table but will appear table like.

Comment: @SATHY: ***"2) freeze row 0 ... scrolling y"***: This is the default behavior using [ttk.Treeview widget](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html). Beside this, i suggest to transpose your `row/columns`, that makes fixing **column 0** obsolete.

Comment: Thanks. Treeview seems to suit the purpose, however, I find that it does not accept Entry widgets to be displayed in the tree view. Any thoughts?

Comment: @SATHY: ***"Entry widgets"***: You'r right, overlooked that you are using `Entry`. ***"Freeze row 0"***: Use a own **top** `Frame` for the heading and sync the `width` of the columns with the data columns. ***"freeze column 0***: Same, own **left** `Frame`. Make **only** the data `Frame` scrollable.

Comment: @SATHYANARAYANANVASUDEVAN: Were you able to find a solution to your problem?